# Jboss domain mode Order of precedence of configuration elements

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

From my understanding of domain mode operations is the following:

- **Host level**: configuration will apply to all servers that are defined in host-slave.xml
- **Server group level**: configuration applies to all servers that are part of the group

I'm using Jboss in domain mode, all slave machines startup pointing to the domain master and includes host-slave.xml, from Jboss admin portal, I have created number of groups, and I have assigned slaves to groups accordingly, however every time I restart jboss on any of the slaves, it comes back pointing to default server groups

```
<server name="server-one" group="main-server-group"/>
<server name="server-two" group="other-server-group">
```

And I have to go to that server and change the group, I have tried modifying group portion in host-slave.xml to correspond to the group I would like them to be part of, however I'm getting exceptions when starting up the server.

What am I missing here? is there is a way to have group level config override settings defined by host-slave.xml

Answer (score 1):

Add `<server name="server-one" group="main-server-group"/>
<server name="server-two" group="other-server-group">`them in the host.xml and start them it should reflect. While start up it checks for host.xml.